# concatenate rows and columns in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have three columns `FirstName,LastNAme,MiddleName`

Table A

```
FirstNAme LastName MiddleName  ID
 James     Tony     peter       1
 Jack      Kallis   end         1
  nnnn      nnn      nnn        2
  mmm       mm       aa         3
```

(there may be ten names with one id or one name with id )

Output for `FullName where  ID=1` should be:

```
FullName
James Tony Peter,Jack Kallis end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `STUFF and FOR XML PATH` method:

```
SELECT 
    STUFF(
       (SELECT
           ',' + ISNULL(FirstName, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(LastName, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(MiddleName, '')
        FROM
           dbo.TableA
        WHERE
           ID = 1
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

This should rendered your desired output.

Comment: Don't forget that if firstname can be null, it has to be wrapped in isnull(firstname, '')